# Is it possible to save the session password in MobaXterm?

Tags: ssh, mobaxterm

I always start up ssh at the start of a work day. MobaXterm asks me for a passphrase the first time I open a terminal for a saved session. Is it possible to save this password so that I don't have to enter it every day?

I am using the free version of MobaXterm on Windows 10. I am logging in to a Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 26):

The following answer is based on mobaXterm Personal Edition v7.3.

```
Settings 
-> Configuration 
-> General 
-> MobaXterm passwords management
-> Automatically save sessions passwords
```

Select `Always`

Answer (score 1):

You can also save SSH key passwords if you enable "Save SSH keys passpharses as well". You can do this under Settings > MobaXterm passwords management.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Mobaxterm 8.4 (I assume this should work for other versions), you click "Setting", then select "Mobaxterm password management". There is couple of knobs so you can your save ssh password for future use.